# open a new view when beacon is detected

Tags: ios, swift, segue, ibeacon

I would just like to ask if it is possible to open a view automatically when a beacon is detected in swift. I am trying to setup an application so that when I attach the beacon to a book when the application is open, it will open a new view to open the details of the book I attached it to. I am trying to start in a simple one like this because in the future I want to have something like a list of all the books I have. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just start with a list, a simple table view driven by an array. When a beacon is detected add it to the array (check if you already have it or not) and reload the table view.

Showing a single view would work in just the same way, you'd just be doing some different work where you reload the table.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I would try that one. Originally I was planning setup like an initial interface which looks similar to a book shelf and when I approach the book I attached one beacon(I am currently using a single beacon and just trying to get the hang of using it first) it will open the details of the book like title and synopsis. Is that possible like an initial view then when a beacon is detected it will automatically open the details view?

Comment: Yes, it is. Start just by logging the details of the detected beacon and go from yhere

Answer (score 0):

Call a function in method "didRangeBeacons" with parameters Beacon detail type. In that function do filter, beacon details and open a view with  animation.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I will gather all the ideas here and try to come up with a solution.